# Three columns for only part of the page

Tags: formatting, columns

Currently I'm working on a resume, but I'm having trouble getting the formatting I want. An example of what I'm trying to do can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUZsa.png) - however, I couldn't even get that to work right (LibreOffice) because the whole document is in 3 columns, when I just need the header as displayed in 3 columns.

I've tried using `\hfill`, but that makes the center column uneven due to the length of the text in the right column. I've tried using a table, but can't seem to get that right. The closest I've gotten is when using the `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set margins to 1 inch
\usepackage{tabularx} % format of addresses at top of document

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\Huge DaimyoKirby}\\
\end{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
123 Main Street & abc1234@myUni.edu & 123 Campus Postoffice \\
MyTown, USA 12345 & 123.456.7890 & CollegeTown, MyState 09876 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

This leaves the columns, however, offcenter like I mentioned before. Is there a way I could have these 3, nicely formatted columns for the top of my resume?

Comment: put it inside the center or prefix by `\noindent`

Comment: unrelated, but remove the `\\ ` after `{\Huge DaimyoKirby}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think three `minipage`s are enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set margins to 1 inch

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\Huge DaimyoKirby}\par\bigskip
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
\raggedright
123 Main Street \par
MyTown, USA 12345 
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
\centering
abc1234@myUni.edu \par
123.456.7890
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33333\textwidth}
\raggedleft
123 Campus Postoffice \par
CollegeTown, MyState 09876
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the electronic address, you could use

```
\texttt{abc1234@myUni.edu}
```

or

```
\url{abc1234@myUni.edu}
```

from the `url` or `hyperref` packages.

Comment: That works great! A few questions though: What does the [b] signify? What exactly is the % doing? I thought that was for comments, so I left it out at first, but (obviously) that didn't turn out correct until I added them back where you had put them.

Comment: @DaimyoKirby `[b]` means that the three `minipage`s will be vertically aligned to their bottom (you can also use `[t]` for top alignment or nothing at all which means the default center alignment). The `%` are important since they are suppressing spurious blank spaces (a carriage return tantamount to a blank space) that otherwise will move the last `minipage` to a new line.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina How do I move the left and right columns slightly upwards so that they start at the same height as the name?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the fancyhdr package for this:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{123 Main Street\\ MyTown, USA 12345}
\chead{{\Huge DaimyoKirby}\\ abc1234@myUni.edu\\ 123.456.7890}
\rhead{123 Campus Postoffice\\ CollegeTown, MyState 09876}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %to get rid of the default rule below the header
```

Comment: With a possible modification to `headheight`.